# Adding another table to sentry2 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Hi I would like to add another table to relate to the sentry users table. I can not seem to find any information on doing this.

I would like to have a table that stores user information and recent activity, lets call it user_activity and have the table be related by user_id.

How can I add this table so that it can be accessed using the sentry service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to think about Sentry in this case, Setry's tables are common tables like any other one, so you can just:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_user_activity_table
```

And create your table relating to users:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserActivityTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_activity', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('<column_name>');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('user_activity', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('user_activity');
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

To use and create your relations, it you can publish Sentry's config:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

Edit `app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php` and change

```
'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User',
```

To your own model (which may be at `app/models/User.php`):

```
'model' => 'User',
```

But your model will have to now extend Sentry's original:

```
class User extends Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User {

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserActivity');
    }

}
```

And create a model for your new table:

```
class UserActivity extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'user_activity';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

And now you can:

```
$user = User::findById(1);

foreach($user->activities as $activity)
{
   echo $activity->description;
   echo $activity->user->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great, now to be able to access this information will I need to create a model specifying the relationship ?